# How to find the Verb that acts on the Object in Python NLP

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

How could I find the Verb that acts on the Object in Python NLP?

For example, "Horses eat carrots", the main verb is "eat". How could I get this result with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nltk.pos_tag`. Try this :

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
is_verb = lambda pos: pos[:2] == 'VB'
str_ = 'Horses eat carrots'
text = word_tokenize(str_)
vbs = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(text) if is_verb(pos)]
```